# Accessors in TypeORM's entity schemas

Tags: typeorm

I want to use TypeORM's entity schemas (http://typeorm.io/#/separating-entity-definition) instead of creating entities with decorators. Using schemas I can implement entity traits easily, just by merging objects before passing them to `new EntitySchema(schema)`.

Still, I can't find a way to define entity object's methods in the schema. Like getters, setters etc. How do I do that?